# identify the conic that represents the equation

Tags: linear-algebra

identify the type of conic that the equation represents and graph it
$\frac{5}{3}y^2 + 4xy - √208y -12 = 0 $
Solución

the associated matrix is

$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 2 & \frac{5}{3} \end{pmatrix}$
the eigenvalues are

$ \lambda _1 = \frac{-4}{3} $ $ \lambda_2 = 3$

$  u_1 = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{-3}{2} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$
$u_2 = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{3} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$
I have not managed to finish it

Comment: The signs of the eigenvalues are all you need to classify the conic.  If they have the same sign you have an ellipse.  If they have different signs you have a hyperbola.  If one is zero you have a parabola.  In the case of an ellipse, however, there is a possibility that you have something degenerate.  e.g. $x^2 + 2y^2 = -1$.  The eigenvectors describe the orientation in the plane.

Comment: How is the graph of this equation?

Comment: A detail: $\sqrt{208}=4\sqrt{13}$

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues (i.e. one positive, one negative) tell us that this is a hyperbola.

considering this parabola in standard form...

$\lambda_1 u^2 + \lambda_2 v^2 = 12\\
-\frac {4}{3} u^2 + 3 v^2 = 12\\
-\frac {u^2}{9} + \frac {v^2}{4} = 1$

$\sqrt {4} = 2$ gives the distance from the center to the closest point on the hyperbola.

The eigenvectors give us the orientation.

$2y - 3x = d$ will run down one line of symmetry of the hyperbola

$3y + 2x = d$ will run between the curves.

Or, $\theta = \arctan {\frac 32}$ is the angle of rotation.

Factoring the equation $(y)(\frac 53y + 4x - 4\sqrt{13}) = 12$ gives the equations for the asymptotes.

$y = 0\\ 5y + 12(x + \sqrt{13}) = 0$

In this case it is pretty quick to see that these intersect at $(\sqrt {13}, 0)$

But we can also use partial derivatives to help us find the center:

$\frac {10}3 y + 4x - \sqrt {208} = 0\\
4y = 0$

Putting it all together.

[image]

Comment: A little detail on the third line : parabola $\to$ hyperbola.

Answer (score 1):

@Doug M has given you a good explanation along the lines you are awaiting.

Here is a different way using the fact that one can transform the **implicit equation**

$$ \frac{5}{3}y^2 + 4xy - \sqrt{208}y -12 = 0\tag{1}$$

into a **cartesian equation** (in fact, not in the classical form $y=f(x)$ but under the form $x=f(y)$ : see (2)). It will allow :

- 1. to identify the type of conic curve, and
- 2. to easily represent the curve.

This is made possible by the fact that in (1), there is only one occurrence of letter $x$. Therefore, our interest is to express it as a function of $y$. Here is how.

Taking into account the fact that $\sqrt{208}=4 \sqrt{13}$, and dividing (1) by 4, we get :

$$xy=-\frac{5}{12}y^2+\sqrt{13}y+3$$

Dividing by $y$, one gets :

$$x=\underbrace{(-\frac{5}{12}y+\sqrt{13})}_{L(y)}+\left(\frac{3}{y}\right) \tag{1}$$

with a linear part (given by function $L$).

As (1) is defined for all values of $y$, we can already rule out the possibility of an ellipse. Besides (1) has an asymptote with equation $y=0$ (btw, the unique forbidden value ; indeed when $y \to 0_+$, for example, then $x \to +\infty$) ; therefore it cannot be a parabola (a parabola hasn't any asymptote) ; as a consequence, it is a hyperbola.

Remark: the other (slant) asymptote is given by equation $x=L(y)$ because $f(y)-L(y)=\frac{3}{y} \to 0$ when $y \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

For a general conic $f(x,y)=Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F$

You have the following classification according to $\Delta=B^2-4AC$

- $\Delta<0$ this is an ellipse
- $\Delta=0$ this is a parabola
- $\Delta>0$ this is an hyperbola

Applying to our case we have $A=0,B=4,C=\frac 53$ gives $\Delta=B^2=16>0$ so this is an hyperbola.

---

Now if you want to reduce it effectively, you have to rotate it first:

Let's set $\begin{cases}x=\cos(t)X+\sin(t)Y\\y=-\sin(t)X+\cos(t)Y\end{cases}$

$f(x,y)=\Big((2(A+C)\sin(t)\cos(t)+B(\cos(t)^2-\sin(t)^2)\Big)XY+\cdots$

Introducing the angle $2t$ you get $\tan(2t)=-\frac B{A+C}$

> Therefore we can rotate our conic by an angle of $-\frac 12\arctan(\frac B{A+C})$ to eliminate the term in $XY$.

Applying to our case we have $A=0,B=4,C=\frac 53$ so $\tan(2t)=-\frac{12}{5}$

But this is a bit tedious though to find $\cos(t)=\frac 3{\sqrt{13}}$ and $\sin(t)=\frac 2{\sqrt{13}}$ from the value of $\tan(2t)$.

Anyway after rotation you get $g(X,Y)=-\frac 43X^2+3Y^2+8X-12Y-12$

Now you can translate it to eliminate the terms in $X$ and $Y$.

Let's set $\begin{cases}X=U+u_0\\Y=V+v_0\end{cases}$

> And you can either substitute and solve or annulate the partial derivatives

$\begin{cases}G_X(u_0,v_0)=-\frac83u_0+8\\G_Y(u_0,v_0)=6v_0-12\end{cases}\implies
u_0=3,\ v_0=2$

After reporting in the equation you get

$$-\frac 43U^2+3V^2=12$$

And you can notice that the coefficients you get are the eigenvalues you calculated.

Comment: All correct, but not applying the power of linear algebra and eigenvalues.